Is there a way to navigate across two Netbeans projects looking for classes and methods?
I work on an application and a library as two Netbeans projects, using PHP. The ability to click on a method or class and navigate to its declaration is useful and time saving.
But I have not found any way to have Netbeans navigate to classes/methods in the library while working on the application. Is there a way to do this?
Attempting to right click and navigate to the library, nothing happens.

can you provide more detail on what you are trying to accomplish?
